# Как обрабатываются HTTP запросы на сервере

Tags: http, запрос

Допустим, есть сервер, и к нему одновременно отправляют HTTP запросы сразу несколько клиентов. Как он их будет обрабатывать - по очереди, или одновременно?

Comment: Если многопоточный - псевдо одновременно. Если нет - очередь

Comment: Почему "псевдо"? Обрабатывать можно и одновременно при наличии нескольких ядер/процессоров.

Comment: Псевдо одновременно скорее потому что так устроена архитектура процессора, а вобщем я вполне с вами согласен. Процессор будет старатся выполнить задачи как можно одновременнее, любой процессор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь всё зависит от типа сервера. Сервера делятся на ***однопоточные***, ***многопоточные*** и ***асинхронные***. В HTTP нет определённого стандарта.

***Однопоточные*** сервера обрабатывают запросы один за другим.

***Многопоточные*** сервера пытаются обработать несколько запросов одновременно (Т. е. пришло 11 запросов, 5 обрабатываются одновременно, а другие 6 ждут, пока закончат обработку первые пять).

***Асинхронные*** сервера действуют по более сложной схеме, но они эффективнее, чем предыдущие. Они могут обрабатывать как один, так и несколько запросов одновременно. Их работа строится на системе ***event loop***, системе событий (Пример: на сервер пришло 3 запроса. Во всех 3 требуется доступ к базе - данных. Но база - данных не может отправить ответ мгновенно, и процессору многопоточных и однопоточных серверов приходится некоторое время ничего не делать. Но не асинхронным серверам. Он берёт I запрос и просит что - либо у базы данных, но не ждёт её ответа, а переходит к запросу II, а затем и III. К моменту окончаний обработки III запроса от базы данных уже приходят данные, нужные запросу I, и сервер начинает работу с пришедшими данными. Аналогичное происходит с ответами от базы данных относительно запроса II и III. В итоге асинхронный сервер сэкономил огромное количество времени, ведь в моменты, когда он должен был ждать ответа от базы, он решил заняться полезным делом).

Comment: где же ты раньше был..