# Как сервер обрабатывает запросы POST?

Tags: php, post

Пытаюсь понять как работает `$_POST`.

Меня интересует взаимодействие сервера с несколькими клиентами одновременно и получение от них данных из формы/форм.

Допустим, 3 человека одновременно отправили заполненную форму на сайте. Скрипт обработчик, понятно, один.

Как эти данные обрабатывает сервер? Ставит в очередь? Или в несколько потоков?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А при чём тут $_POST?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, данные от всех трех(условно) форм попадают в массив $_POST. Во всяком случае скрипт-обработчик же получает данные именно из $_POST. Получает, сохраняет в переменные, которые потом записываются в БД.

Comment: А массив $_GET вас не смущает?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706865/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5
https://habr.com/ru/post/251501/
$_POST просто массив, в который php складывает всё что постом получает и дальше с этим работает. А передаются данные на сервер в этот массив методом через http методом post.

Comment: В первом приближении можно считать что на *каждый* запрос запускается новый скрипт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае для каждого запроса запустится свой отдельный экземпляр вашего PHP скрипта.

Если это будут одновременные запросы, то одновременно запустится три экземпляра.

Тут уже у вас полная свобода действий. Хотите обрабатывать запросы параллельно? Нет проблем, всё уже так работает. Хотите, чтобы в один момент времени работал только один запрос? Тоже нет проблем, используйте или транзакции в БД, или [семафоры](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.sem.php), или хоть [`flock`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) подключите. Десяток вариантов решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1):

В общем все зависит от сервера. Под сервером надо понимать процесс который работает на физическом сервере и предоставляет, некий интерфейс (порт, сокет) для WEB это два порта по умолчанию 80 и 443, http и https соответственно. Примером таких серверов будут служить следующие пакеты:

1. nginx
2. apache
3. php -S

Что бы глубже понимать что такое `$_POST` в php, надо посмотреть на саму цепочку, как доходит запрос до сервера? А схематично это выглядит так:

> браузер -> http -> (nginx -> php)

В php можно получить прямой доступ к потоку ввода и вывода https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php но все же нас интересует от куда `post`? Запрос http это ничто иное как файл который имеет заголовки и тело запроса

```
Content-type: application/json


{"test":test}
```

как пример такого запроса. Когда он отправляется методом `POST`, то этот файлик записывается в stdin в порт сервера, после чего сервер (nginx) формирует запрос к интерпретатору php с использованием переменных окружения https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php. После чего уже сам интерпретатор парсит строку относительно `content-type` и формирует массив `$_POST`, который суперглобален, и доступен в любой части скрипта.

Многие сервера обрабатывают запросы асинхронно, простыми словами запускают на каждый запрос новый `instance` процесс для обработки запроса, после отработки процесс завершается. `POST` для каждого формируется свой.